# Как объединить две таблицы без общего ключа?

Tags: sql, join, like, where

Имею 1 таблицу 'ta' в которой столбцы:
abonent и direction

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И 2 таблицу 'city_code' в которой столбцы:
city   и      code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как объединить две таблицы по столбцам direction и code? Ведь общего ключа нет, а надо написать что направление звонка - это Москва итд.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Либо добавьте ключи в существующую таблицу, либо создайте третью таблицу-связку и через нее соединяйте.

Comment: Их нельзя никак объединить, если не расписать четкие правила как direction должен превращаться в code. А вот если правила будут, тогда можно брать строковые функции mysql и преобразовывать одно в другое, согласно этим правилам

Comment: Готов добавить ключи или третью таблицу. Что угодно. У самого идей нет по этому поводу, буду рад подсказкам.

Comment: Так вам же ж уже подсказали. Осталось только выбрать подходящее вам решение и реализовать. Соответствие, скорее всего придется делать вручную. Иногда вообще бывает полезным пересмотреть архитектуру данных в БД, все грохнуть и заново заполнить :)

Comment: Вручную не вариант, там около 20 тыс. строк. Это тарификация звонков вытащенная из учрежденческой АТС. И есть задача определить все иногородние звонки. А подсказку я не понял ввиду неопытности. Поэтому, если можно, то объясните на пальцах).

Comment: Покопайтесь в таблицах. Должен быть механизм связи direction и code. Потому что обычно direction определяется по code или direction начинается с code или code входит в direction, или есть отдельная таблица связи direction-code. В крайнем случае поищите в "Российская система и план нумерации")

Comment: В таблице 1 в 'direction' есть кусочек из 'code'. И вот как это увязать? Если бы в одной таблице то оператор LIKE '8495%', а вот как в разных таблицах это связать не могу домыслить

Comment: Можно попробовать в таблицу direction добавить дополнительное поле code. Если direction внутренний - указать специальный код или оставить пустым. Это соответствие direction-code обычно редко изменяется, только при переделке физической или логической структуры. Если только нужно вытащить иногородние звонки, то они обычно выделены - их должно быть очень немного.